# How to debug a site move, for a PHP5/MySQL web application

Tags: php, mysql, server, system-administration

I have been running a PHP site for years on my own servers. I recently purchased a dedicated server package and am trying to move my site to the dedicated server. I recently upgraded to PHP 5, and my current server is running PHP 5.6.16. I moved the files and the database, and put it in a live test domain, but the site is not functioning properly on the new dedicated server. Several key scripts are non-functional. I made sure that the dedicated server is running a version of 5.6. I have configured it to the same settings I have on the old server. I can see that the site is talking to the MySQL database. I turned on error reporting and I see no significant errors suggesting why these important scripts are now non-functional. I made sure the include path is there, and if it wasn't nothing would work. What am I overlooking? What could be different between one server and the other that might impact PHP functionality? I'm basically at my wits end here, so if these seems stupid please forgive me, but I don't know where to look next.

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: Sounds like you need to hire a consultant. This is not a programming problem. I'm kind of concerned that it took twelve years to update to PHP 5, if you're running your own servers it's *imperative* you stay patched and up to date.

Answer (score 3):

Start with the basics.

- Does your web server respond to static page requests?
- Is your web server configured to use PHP?
- Can your web server execute and/or connect to PHP?
- If you have a simple script with `<?php phpinfo();` in it, does it work?
- Are all the expected modules there in your `phpinfo()` output?
- Do you have rewrite rules that need to be reconfigured?  (Check your web server error log.  Check your response status codes.)

Assuming PHP is all good, move into your application.

- Are you absolutely sure error logging is on?  (Again, check `phpinfo()` output.  Try to force an error, maybe a syntax error or something and see if you see the error.)
- How do you know your application is connecting to MySQL?
- Start with a basic script that just echos some things.
- Comment out large swaths of code and see if you can narrow down the problem that way, re-enabling chunks as you go.  (You want to bi-sect the problem, cutting in half and in half and in half until you figure out exactly what the issue is.)

Other system-level things to check...

- File system permissions?  (See also https://serverfault.com/questions/48587/is-there-a-linux-log-for-when-a-user-is-denied-access-to-files-due-to-permission, for Linux.)
- Firewalls?  (Are you *sure* you can actually access MySQL over the network?)
- Disk?  (Are you out of space?  Are your partitions set up correct?  Is `/tmp` full?)

Once you figure out the problem, some advice:

- Do this sort of thing regularly.  Write a provisioning script to build yourself a new machine from one command, and do it regularly.  These days with cloud providers (physical hardware or not) there's no reason you can't blow away your application servers on a regular basis, and re-provision them.  Consider making this your system upgrade strategy.  (Why reboot to get a new kernel when you can just have a whole new server with the new kernel and other patches, that you can cut over to?)
- Ensure your development environment closely matches your production environment. (Consider [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) for this.)
- You're using version control, right?  If not, start using version control so that you can hack on your code for things like this and easily roll back when done.

Comment: Thank you, Brad. You do give me some things to work on. I know there is a MySQL connection because there are dozens of scripts successfully querying the database. I'll look at the modules, permissions, and disk space.

Comment: @DRice How do you know there are dozens of scripts successfully querying the database?

Comment: Because I have tested them. This site is very large - I have hundreds of pages of scripts from forums to home pages. I have navigated large portions of the site, and tested the functionality, including using the search features to produce results.

Comment: @DRice So, your site *does* work?  That totally changes the context of your question.  In this case, you probably are just using some deprecated code in some places.  Again, double/triple check your error logging.

Comment: Right, but I'm using PHP 5 in both cases. On the old server it is PHP 5.6.16 and on the new server it is 5.6.31. HOWEVER when I first set up the new server it was using an older version of PHP - 5.4.16. I upgraded it to 5.6.31 in order to resolve the issue, but it didn't.

Comment: @DRice PHP is also very configurable in php.ini... might be an issue there.  You can compare configs by comparing the output of `phpinfo()`, but it would be better to get your error log working so you can see what's going on.  Perhaps you had a warning earlier that was being hidden, but now it's breaking things?

Comment: Hi - yes, I have the error log working, and it is kicking out errors, but things like undefined index, nothing that should break the functionality. However I think it's got to be the code since I can't find anything else wrong. I did compare configs, and adjusted accordingly, same result. It's maddening.

Comment: @DRice `undefined index` can very well be a problem that should break something.  Follow my earlier advice and bi-sect your code to find the specific issue.